# Unable to grab div text with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, error-handling, css-selectors

I just started working with beautiful soup and python in general and want to grab data from a local e-commerce website. I have successfully grabbed the title, time and URL but I am having a hard time with the price. The text I want to grab is `<div class="amount--3NTpl">GH₵ 1,300,000</div>`. I tried `price = soup.find("div", class_="amount--3NTpl").text` but I get an error when I try to export to csv however the script works when I completely remove the price.

Here's my script;

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
    
def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    if not response.ok:
        print("Server responded:", response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    return soup


def get_detail_data(soup):
    try:
        title = soup.find("h1", class_="title--3s1R8").text
    except:
        title = ""

    try:
        date = soup.find("h3", class_="sub-title--37mkY").text
    except:
        date = ""

    try:
        price = soup.find("div", class_="amount--3NTpl").text
    except:
        price = ""

    data = {
        "title": title,
        "date": date,
        "price": price,
    }

    return data


def get_index_data(soup):
    try:
        links = soup.findAll("a", class_="card-link--3ssYv gtm-ad-item")
    except:
        links = []

    urls = ["https://tonaton.com"+item.get("href") for item in links]

    return urls


def write_csv(data, url):
    with open("tonatonoutput.csv", "a") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

        row = [data["title"], data["date"], data["price"], url]

        writer.writerow(row)


def main():
    url = "https://tonaton.com/en/ads/ghana/property?page=1"

    products = get_index_data(get_page(url))

    for link in products:
        data = get_detail_data(get_page(link))
        write_csv(data, link)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error message;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MUG/PycharmProjects/ReProject/tonatonscrapper.py", line 72, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/MUG/PycharmProjects/ReProject/tonatonscrapper.py", line 68, in main
    write_csv(data, link)
  File "C:/Users/MUG/PycharmProjects/ReProject/tonatonscrapper.py", line 58, in write_csv
    writer.writerow(row)
  File "C:\Users\MUG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x82' in position 76: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try strip the `GH₵` from the price.

Change the code that gets the price value to:

```
...

    try:
        price = soup.find("div", class_="amount--3NTpl").text
        price = price.split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
    except:
        price = ""

...
```